# If a complex number $z$ satisfies $|2z+10+10i| \leq 5\sqrt{3}-5$ then find ....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Problem :

If a complex number $z$ satisfies $|2z+10+10i| \leq 5\sqrt{3}-5$ then find the least principal argument

My approach :

$|2z+10+10i| \leq 5\sqrt{3}-5 = |z+(5+5i)| \leq \frac{5\sqrt{3}-5}{2}$

This represent a circle whose centre is $(-5,-5) $ and radius is $\frac{5}{2}(\sqrt{3}-1)$

This circle is in third quadrant and if we join origin with centre of circle and draw tangent from origin to this circle, we get a triangle $\Delta OAB$ where O is origin, A is centre and B is point on circle from where tangent passes drawn from origin and OA is origin and centre.

Let $\angle AOB =\theta$

then $sin\theta = \frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$ after simplification.

$\Rightarrow \theta = 15^{\circ}$ This is the case when I have taken tangent near to x axis point on circle, if I will take point on other side of circle which is near to y axis then I will get the same $\theta$

Now how to get the least argument. Please suggest will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

The principal argument of $z$ will be the argument of $B$ that is the argument of the complex $A$ minus $15º$. If $B$ is the tangent point closest to real axis.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm just using what Sultan already evaluated. I just supplemented the solution.

Comment: Oh, yeah, silly me, didn't read past the beginning.